# What is the meaning of this on a site's Robots.txt page?

Tags: web-scraping

I've been trying to scrape a website's data to build a game out of the database and I'm frequently getting blocked with a CAPTCHA request. When I checked the Robots.txt file for the site, I see this:

```
Disallow:   /a/
Disallow:   /contact-us/
```

What is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google docs.

> A robots. txt file tells search engine crawlers which pages or files
> the crawler can or can't request from your site. This is used mainly
> to avoid overloading your site with requests; it is not a mechanism
> for keeping a web page out of Google.